# Back up contents of FTPS to local folder

Tags: windows, backup, ftps

I want to back up the contents of one of my servers to a local folder.

The server has a FTPS service set up and running (regular FTP is not an option).
I want to copy the contents of the FTP into a local folder on my windows 2003 machine running at home on a weekly basis.

I really dont need to keep a historical record of removed files so if a file is removed on the FTP server it should also be removed in the backup at next sync.

So my question is: What is the best way to keep a local copy of an **FTPS** server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) for that.
Open Source and free.

Make a Task so that you run it once a week or so automatically.

You should be able to script it according to your needs.

[Scripting Documentation of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)

No need to pay money for something trivial as that.

For having the deleted files removed you might need some PowerShell scripts as well though.

Something like:

```
Download Copy (WinSCP)
Download NewCopy (WinSCP)
get Diff NewCopy vs Copy, remove the deleted files (PowerShell)
```

As for the details , they depend as usual, and sadly i did not yet exactly do something like that myself ( i would use cygwin + rsync , but afaik this would not work and is a bit harder to install)

Comment: This was the solution I actually went with a while ago so Ill give you the points :)

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt thank you, i realised your question was a year old only after i did write the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to expose some kind of network service on the backup target server. FTP, SFTP, FTPS, SSH, VPN... something. Access that service from the backup source. For example, mount the remote SFTP service as a network drive using a third party tool like WebDrive. Or, if you set up a VPN connection to the backup target, connect to the VPN and then mount a CIFS share across the VPN. Then use Robocopy with the `/mir` option (among others) to copy your directories across.

Comment: Know of any free alternatives to WebDrive? It costs 70USD.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a third party software to do the job, there's this nice free tool I heard about but never got the chance to use: http://www.ipswitchft.com/products/moveitFreely/index.aspx

If you prefer something with a GUI, here's another one: http://www.iperiusbackup.com/ftp-backup.aspx

Thanks,

Comment: IperiousBackup only seems to be able to send backups from the computer it is running on to a FTPS server, it dosent seem to be able to take backups of an FTPS. Trying out MoveItFreely now ;)